How to find the bounds of integration from the equations of the surfaces that enclose a volume of triple integral and solve it?
I'm supposed to find the volume enclosed between the two surfaces $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ and $x^2+y^2=3z$,
when I did it in cartesian coordinates I got some bounds but the integral became a mess.
Here are the bounds in cartesian:
$$\left\{ \left(x,y,z\right)\left|\begin{array}{c}
-1\leq x\leq1\\
-\sqrt{3-x^{2}}\leq y\leq\sqrt{3-x^{2}}\\
\frac{x^{2}+y^{2}}{3}\leq z\leq\sqrt{4-x^{2}-y^{2}}
\end{array}\right.\right\}  $$
I then tried to switch to cylindrical coordinates but that failed as well and then tried to switch to spherical coordinates but now I'm not sure of my bounds, I can picture in my head the volume in Cartesian which helped me find the bounds there, but in spherical coordinates this intuition is mostly gone.
The bounds for spherical (that I found so far) are as follows:
$$\left\{ \left(\rho,\theta,\phi\right)\left|\begin{array}{c}
\frac{3\cos\phi}{\sin^{2}\phi}\leq\rho\leq2\\
0\leq\theta\leq2\pi\\
0\leq\phi\leq
\end{array}\right.\right\}   $$
I got the bounds for $\rho$ from playing with the conversion and the top and bottom functions. the bounds for $\theta$ are like that since it's symmetrical around the $\phi$ axis.
but now for the bounds of $\phi$  I'm not sure, it has to start at 0 but figure out the upper bound for it.
Am I wrong altogether and should pursue a different approach?

This question is similar to: Find the volume of the region bounded by a sphere and a paraboloid using cylindrical and spherical coordinates.. Found using Approach$0$.

I note that the problem statement is ambiguous: the paraboloid partitions the interior of the sphere into two volumes, either/both of which are bounded by the two surfaces...

Assuming that you want the upper partition like you have been doing in your problem, it is actually much easier to set up the integral in spherical with the intention of doing the $\phi$ integral first, i.e. $$x^2+y^2=3z \implies \phi = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{-3+\sqrt{9+4\rho^2}}{2\rho}\right)$$ by quadratic formula. Then you have $0<\phi<\cos^{-1}(\cdots)$, $0<\rho<2$, and $0<\theta<2\pi$

@AnneBauval thanks! this indeed proved useful i had some mistakes that made it impossible initially

Use cylindrical coordinates because of the symmetry about the $z$-axis. I don't know why you dismissed it so quickly. Spherical coordinates requires breaking the integration into two separate pieces.

@TedShifrin spherical coordinates can actually be done in one integral as in my comment above, by ordering $d\phi$ first. This approach is also very useful for the more traditional "hamburger" solid defined by $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq $ and $x^2+y^2+(z-1)^2\leq 1$ because the resulting integral in spherical coordinates leaves only polynomials.

@NinadMunshi Granted, but in my experience, far more difficult for beginning students to visualize and execute.

@TedShifrin it hasn't been a problem for me to teach first time students this technique, usually with the aid of telling them to draw the surfaces on a $\rho \phi$ plane (or the cylindrical $rz$ plane with the circular arcs). This is exactly how boundaries are found with the generic $uv$ substitutions as well.

Probably wise to keep the combination $x^2+y^2$ together.  Eliminating them between the bounds, we have
$$  3z + z^2 = 4  \text{,}  $$
having roots $z = 1$ and $z = -4$.  The equation $x^2 + y^2  + z^2 = 4$ is a sphere of radius $2$, so $z = -4$ is a spurious intersection.  (Maybe there's a complex intersection there, but this is a real geometry problem, so we don't even think about that.)
When $z = 1$, either equation gives $x^2 + y^2 = 3$.  This tells me your first cartesian bound is incorrect.  It should be
$$ -\sqrt{3} < x < \sqrt{3} \text{.}  $$
Weirdly, you have the correct bound for $y$.
But this is the wrong order.  Keep the combination together.  So our first variable is $0 < z < 2$.  For $0 < z \leq 1$, the horizontal slice through the volume is a disk bounded by the paraboloid, so with radius $\sqrt{3z}$.  For $1 \leq z < 2$, the horizontal slice through the volume is a disk bounded by the sphere, so with radius $\sqrt{4-z^2}$.  So a pretty good way to go is to write the sum of two integrals, each over $z$ with integrand the area of the correct disk (don't even waste time pretending a disk is an area whose integral you have to find).  Alternatively, if one must write as triple integrals, a sum of two triple integrals: $$\int_{0}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{3z}}^{\sqrt{3z}}\int_{-\sqrt{3z-x^2}}^{\sqrt{3z-x^2}} \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}z + \int_{1}^{2} \int_{-\sqrt{4-z^2}}^{\sqrt{4-z^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{4-z^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-z^2 - x^2}}  \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}z \text{.}  $$
Finally, if one is required to write as a single triple integral, then, as you have done, keep the $z$ integral for last.  Since we can easily determine that the paraboloid is below the sphere (substitute $(x,y) = (0,0)$ into both and find $z = 0$ on the paraboloid and $z = 2$ on the sphere), we have
$$  \int_{-\sqrt{3}}^{\sqrt{3}} \int_{-\sqrt{3-x^2}}^{\sqrt{3-x^2}} \int_{(x^2 + y^2)/3}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}} \,\mathrm{d}z \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}x  \text{.}  $$
